# Not working mock for the local variable - Getting Specified Key does not exist (Service Amazon S3)

Tags: java, junit4, powermockito

This is my actual method which I want to test using mock

```
   @Override
    public void processTransaction(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        AmazonS3 s3Client = null;
        s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());
        url = String.format("%s%s%s", tenantConfig.getSchemaName(), PATH_LOC_NEW, fileName);
        region = System.getProperty("aws.region.prefix") != null ? System.getProperty("aws.region.prefix") : "";
        bucket = String.format("%s%s-%s", System.getProperty("aws.Environment"), region, "gfcp-tenant");
        S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucket, url));
        InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(object.getObjectContent());
        ObjectMetadata meta = new ObjectMetadata();
    }
```

Here is my test logic but it seems it is not mocking `AmazonS3Client AmazonS3` that is the reason I am getting exception

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({TransactionProcessingService.class})
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.net.ssl.*","javax.security.*","javax.management.*","javax.crypto.*"})
public class TransactionProcessingServiceTest {

    @Test
    public void testProcessTransaction() throws Exception {
        DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain credentialMock = PowerMockito.mock(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(credentialMock);
        AmazonS3Client s3Client = PowerMockito.mock(AmazonS3Client.class);
        HttpRequestBase httprequest = PowerMockito.mock(HttpRequestBase.class);
        S3Object object= PowerMockito.mock(S3Object.class);
        InputStream in = PowerMockito.mock(InputStream.class);
        object.setObjectContent(new S3ObjectInputStream(in, httprequest));
        when(s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("local_vittal-gfcp-tenant", "cdta/TransactionProcessing/New/junit_test_file.acf")))
                            .thenReturn(object);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(AmazonS3Client.class).withArguments(credentialMock).thenReturn(s3Client);
        transactionProcessingService.processTransaction(exchange);

    }   
}
```

Can anyone please help me out.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now.
I need to use implementation class also in @PrepareForTest like -

```
@PrepareForTest(TransactionProcessingServiceImpl.class)
```